# Essential supremum of a conditional expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

Given the function
\begin{equation}
  P(x,t) := \sup\limits_{t \le \tau \le T} E\left( g(X^{t,x}_{\tau}) \right)
\end{equation}
where $X^{t,x}$ is the unique solution to the SDE
\begin{equation}
  X_u = x + \int\limits_t^u \mu(X_s, s) \, ds + \int\limits_t^u \sigma(X_s, s) \, dB_s
\end{equation}
for $x >0$, $t \in [0,T]$, $u \in [t,T]$ and $\tau$ is a stopping time with $P(\tau \in [t,T]) =1$ and $g$ is a continuous R-valued function.

Then we have for the process $X = X^{0,s}$ (defined analogously)
\begin{equation}
  P(X_t, t) = \text{ess sup}_{t \le \tau \le T} E\left(g(X_{\tau}) \, | \, \mathcal{F}_t \right)
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(B_s: s \in [0,t])$.

I found this statement but I don't know how to argue correctly to get that relation. Somehow the expectation in the definition of the function $P$ is conditioned on $X^{t,x}_t = x$ which is obviously an a.s.-event, but what happens when I have a random variable instead of a deterministic $x$? And how do I get the equality of the supremum and the essential supremum?

Maybe you can have a look at my attempt I have figured out so far:
\begin{align}
  P(X_t, t) & = \sup\limits_{t \le \tau \le T} E\left( g(X^{t,X_t}_{\tau}) \right) \\
            & = \sup\limits_{t \le \tau \le T} E\left( g(X^{t,X_t}_{\tau}) \, | \, X^{t,X_t}_t = X_t \right) \\
            & = \sup\limits_{t \le \tau \le T} E\left( g(X^{t,X_t}_{\tau}) \, | \, X_t \right) \\
            & \text{(Is the expected value $E( \cdot \, | \, X^{t,X_t}_t = X_t)$ really equal to the conditional expectation $E( \cdot \, | \, X_t)$? If so, how do I argue here precisely?)} \\
            & = \sup\limits_{t \le \tau \le T} E\left( g(X_{\tau}) \, | \, X_t \right) \\
            & \text{(flow property of solutions to the SDE)} \\
            & = \sup\limits_{t \le \tau \le T} E\left( g(X_{\tau}) \, | \, \mathcal{F}_t \right) \\
            & \text{(Markov property of solutions to the SDE)} \\
            & = \text{ess sup}_{t \le \tau \le T} E\left( g(X_{\tau}) \, | \, \mathcal{F}_t \right) \\
            & \text{(???)}
\end{align}
Has anyone an idea how to get the a.s. equality of $\sup$ and ess sup? I think the key to that is the measurability of the sup, but I have no idea how to prove that for the set of stopping times.

Comment: The proof should use the fact that, conditionally on $F_t$ and $X_t=x$, the process $(X_{t+s})_{s\geqslant0}$ coincides in distribution with $X^{t,x}$. The continuity of $g$ is assumed, probably to avoid measurability issues. What is your source?

Comment: The original source is "A probabilistic approach of the reduite" by N. El Karoui from 1992 where they deal with optimal stopping for Markov processes. It is stated that the reduite $P$ is equal to the Snell envelope of $g(X)$, but I applied it to a very simpler case I have to deal with in my thesis. Up to that point I worked with the Snell envelope and now I'm trying to find the connection between $P$ and the Snell-Envelope to be able to express the optimal stopping time for my actual problem in terms of $P$.

Comment: El Karoui AND Lepeltier AND Millet, then. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Isn't the coincidence of the two processes in distribution actually the flow property of solutions? Is the rest of the argument correct?